# How to change the name of an existing menuitem

Tags: xml, menuitem, odoo-8

I'd like to change the name of menu 'Opportunities' in `Sales/Sales/Opportunities` (CRM).

I tried this code :

```
<menuitem 
        id="crm.menu_crm_opportunities"
        parent="base.menu_sales"
        name="Affaire"
        sequence="4"
        groups="base.group_sale_salesman,base.group_sale_manager"/>
```

But it doesn't work; what would I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <record model="ir.ui.menu" id="crm.menu_crm_opportunities">
        <field name='name'>Affaire</field>
    </record>
```

Please use the above code to change the name of existing menu Item name.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this one

```
**<field name="name">Opportunities</field>**
```

in

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="crm_case_category_act_oppor11">
    <field name="name">Opportunities</field>
    <field name="res_model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,graph,form,calendar</field>
    <field name="domain">[('type','=','opportunity')]</field>
    <field name="context">{
            'stage_type': 'opportunity',
            'default_type': 'opportunity',
            'default_user_id': uid
        }
    </field>
    <field name="view_id" eval="False"/>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="crm.view_crm_case_opportunities_filter"/>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p>
            Odoo helps you keep track of your sales pipeline to follow
            up potential sales and better forecast your future revenues.
        </p><p>
            You will be able to plan meetings and phone calls from
            opportunities, convert them into quotations, attach related
            documents, track all discussions, and much more.
        </p>
    </field>
</record>


<menuitem name="Opportunities" id="menu_crm_opportunities" parent="base.menu_sales" sequence="4"
        action="crm_case_category_act_oppor11"
        groups="base.group_sale_salesman,base.group_sale_manager"/>
```

in crm_lead_menu.xml